# Dont hide if it hasClass in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Okay, start out saying this is hard to explain with words only.

So i have setup a example here: http://jsfiddle.net/AFhvS/2/

I have a code in PHP, that show() the span element with X `.sletindtastningfelt` if it's filled.

In the jsfiddle, it's placed at the bottom in the js field.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#smeal-1-1').show();
    $('#smeal-1-1').addClass("upstartRemoveClass");

    $('#smeal-1-2').show();
    $('#smeal-1-2').addClass("upstartRemoveClass");
});
```

Ok so it appears X infront of the first two input fields now.

What it does now is that when you click on one of the 4 `tr` (input fields), it hides the other X's and keeps the one infront of the field. This is caused by the `.end().siblings().find('.sletindtastningfelt').hide();`

I wish to change this procedure if it has the class "upstartRemoveClass". So if it has the class `upstartRemoveClass` it should not hide, like the rest, when you click on a `tr` (input field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `not`?

Like this:

```
.end().siblings().find('.sletindtastningfelt').not(".upstartRemoveClass").hide();
```

Does that give you the result you're looking for?

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I just found the jquery not() in another window, and then saw this and tested. Works prima!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use [`:not(.className)`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
.end().siblings().find('.sletindtastningfelt:not(.upstartRemoveClass)').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

This just requires a condition:

```
if($("someElement").hasClass("upstartRemoveClass"))
{
   // do something
}
```

Comment: The problem with hasClass is that it only looks on one element.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above using `.not()` or `:not()` are valid, but you can also change the logic a bit, and show any `.upstartRemoveClass` after hiding the rest:

```
$(this).closest('tr')
       .find('.sletindtastningfelt')
       .show()
       .end()
       .siblings()
       .find('.sletindtastningfelt')
       .hide();

$('.upstartRemoveClass').show();
```

In this case, it will probably not be the best choice, but it can be useful sometimes, for example to remove complexity.